# How to Add a Single Row's Documents from Array Together

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection with one entry like this:

```
{
"gstin": "22AAAAA1301E1T8",
"sname": "RR&Co",
"fp": "112016",
"gt": 1234567.89,
"curr_gt": 1232.00,
"b2b": [{
        "ctin": "32DS233TY781233",
        "inum": "TEST12345",
        "idt": "15-11-2016",
        "ival": 20000.01,
        "pos": "GJ",
        "rchrg": "N",
        "type": "Regular",
        "itms": [{
            "num": 1,
            "itm_det": {
                "rt": 5,
                "txval": 15000.23,
                "iamt": 1000.20,
                "camt": 1000.25,
                "samt": 0,
                "csamt": 0
            },
            "itc": {
                "elg": "ip",
                "tc_i": 0.0,
                "tc_c": 0.0,
                "tc_s": 0.0,
                "tc_cs": 0.0
            }
        },
        {
            "num": 2,
            "itm_det": {
                "rt": 6,
                "txval": 16000.23,
                "iamt": 1600.20,
                "camt": 1600.25,
                "samt": 100,
                "csamt": 50
            },
            "itc": {
                "elg": "ip",
                "tc_i": 2.0,
                "tc_c": 1.0,
                "tc_s": 3.0,
                "tc_cs": 5.0
            }
        }],
        "custom": {
            "custom_<<attr1_name>>": "",
            "custom_<<attr2_name>>": "",
            "custom_<<attr3_name>>": "",
            "custom_<<attr4_name>>": ""
        }
    },
    {
        "ctin": "32DS233TY781234",
        "inum": "GUEST12345",
        "idt": "18-11-2016",
        "ival": 10000.01,
        "pos": "GJ",
        "rchrg": "Y",
        "type": "RD",
        "itms": [{
            "num": 1,
            "itm_det": {
                "rt": 6,
                "txval": 14000.23,
                "iamt": 1200.20,
                "camt": 1300.25,
                "samt": 0,
                "csamt": 0
            },
            "itc": {
                "elg": "ip",
                "tc_i": 0.0,
                "tc_c": 0.0,
                "tc_s": 0.0,
                "tc_cs": 0.0
            }
        }],
        "custom": {
            "custom_<<attr1_name>>": "",
            "custom_<<attr2_name>>": "",
            "custom_<<attr3_name>>": "",
            "custom_<<attr4_name>>": ""
        }
    },
    {
        "ctin": "32DS233TY781235",
        "inum": "HOST12345",
        "idt": "18-11-2016",
        "ival": 20000.01,
        "pos": "GJ",
        "rchrg": "Y",
        "type": "RD",
        "itms": [{
            "num": 1,
            "itm_det": {
                "rt": 5,
                "txval": 16000.23,
                "iamt": 1300.20,
                "camt": 1400.25,
                "samt": 0,
                "csamt": 0
            },
            "itc": {
                "elg": "ip",
                "tc_i": 0.0,
                "tc_c": 0.0,
                "tc_s": 0.0,
                "tc_cs": 0.0
            }
        }],
        "custom": {
            "custom_<<attr1_name>>": "",
            "custom_<<attr2_name>>": "",
            "custom_<<attr3_name>>": "",
            "custom_<<attr4_name>>": ""
        }
    }
],
"imp_g": [{
    "port_code": "INATT2",
    "gstin": "27AHQPA8875L1ZU",
    "boe_num": "25662",
    "boe_dt": "18-04-2016",
    "boe_val": 23456.20,
    "txval": 100000.00,
    "type": "Import",
    "itms": [{
        "num": 1,
        "itm_det": {
            "rt": 5,
            "txval": 15000.23,
            "iamt": 1000.20,
            "camt": 1000.25,
            "samt": 0,
            "csamt": 0
        },
        "itc": {
            "elg": "ip",
            "tc_i": 0.0,
            "tc_c": 0.0,
            "tc_s": 0.0,
            "tc_cs": 0.0
        }
    }],
    "custom": {
        "custom_<<attr1_name>>": "",
        "custom_<<attr2_name>>": "",
        "custom_<<attr3_name>>": "",
        "custom_<<attr4_name>>": ""
    }
}],
"cdnr": [{
    "ctin": "32DS233TY781223",
    "ntty": "credit",
    "nt_num": "123356a",
    "nt_dt": "13-04-2016",
    "pos": "MH",
    "itms": [{
        "num": 1,
        "itm_det": {
            "rt": 5,
            "txval": 15000.23,
            "iamt": 1000.20,
            "camt": 1000.25,
            "samt": 0,
            "csamt": 0
        },
        "itc": {
            "elg": "ip",
            "tc_i": 0.0,
            "tc_c": 0.0,
            "tc_s": 0.0,
            "tc_cs": 0.0
        }
    }],
    "custom": {
        "custom_<<attr1_name>>": "",
        "custom_<<attr2_name>>": "",
        "custom_<<attr3_name>>": "",
        "custom_<<attr4_name>>": ""
    }
}],
"nil": [{
    "sply_ty": "INTRB2B",
    "cpddr": 123.45,
    "exptdsply": 123.45,
    "nildsply": 1470.85,
    "ngsply": 1258.5,
    "custom": {
        "custom_<<attr1_name>>": "",
        "custom_<<attr2_name>>": "",
        "custom_<<attr3_name>>": "",
        "custom_<<attr4_name>>": ""
    }
}],
"isd": [{
    "gstin": "123456a",
    "ty": "isd",
    "inum": "1213A",
    "idt": "13-04-2016",
    "itms": [{
        "num": 1,
        "itm_det": {
            "ig_cr": 123,
            "cg_cr": 12,
            "sg_cr": 18,
            "cs_cr": 9
        },
        "itc": {
            "ig_amt": 123.0,
            "cg_amt": 234.0,
            "sg_amt": 345.00,
            "cs_amt": 1000.25
        }
    }],
    "custom": {
        "custom_<<attr1_name>>": "",
        "custom_<<attr2_name>>": "",
        "custom_<<attr3_name>>": "",
        "custom_<<attr4_name>>": ""
    }
}],
"tctd": [{
    "ty": "tds",
    "ctin": "123456a",
    "grval": 123.00,
    "slval": 234.00,
    "nt_val": 345.00,
    "iamt": 14.52,
    "camt": 78.52,
    "samt": 12.9,
    "custom": {
        "custom_<<attr1_name>>": "",
        "custom_<<attr2_name>>": "",
        "custom_<<attr3_name>>": "",
        "custom_<<attr4_name>>": ""
    }
}],
"atr": [{
    "ty": "P",
    "ad_amt": 10000.00,
    "month": "mm",
    "inter": [{
        "rt": 18,
        "txval": 15000.23,
        "iamt": 0,
        "csamt": 0,
        "pos": "GJ"
    }, {
        "rt": 18,
        "txval": 15000.23,
        "iamt": 0,
        "csamt": 0,
        "pos": "KA"
    }],
    "intra": [{
        "rt": 18,
        "txval": 15000.23,
        "crt": 9.00,
        "camt": 1000.25,
        "srt": 9.00,
        "samt": 0,
        "csamt": 0
    }],
    "custom": {
        "custom_<<attr1_name>>": "",
        "custom_<<attr2_name>>": "",
        "custom_<<attr3_name>>": "",
        "custom_<<attr4_name>>": ""
    }
}],
"itc": [{
    "amt_type": "Amount in terms of rule 2(2) of ITC Rules",
    "action": "ad",
    "iamt": 14.52,
    "camt": 78.52,
    "samt": 12.9,
    "csamt": 12.3,
    "custom": {
        "custom_<<attr1_name>>": "",
        "custom_<<attr2_name>>": "",
        "custom_<<attr3_name>>": "",
        "custom_<<attr4_name>>": ""
    }
}],
"itcm": [{
    "mis_type": "ITC claimed on mismatched/duplication of invoice /debit notes",
    "action": "add",
    "iamt": 14.52,
    "camt": 78.52,
    "samt": 12.9,
    "csamt": 12.3,
    "custom": {
        "custom_<<attr1_name>>": "",
        "custom_<<attr2_name>>": "",
        "custom_<<attr3_name>>": "",
        "custom_<<attr4_name>>": ""
    }
}],
"hsn": [{
    "num": 1,
    "ty": "hsn",
    "desc": "hsnsummary",
    "uqc": "1",
    "qty": 2.05,
    "txval": 10.23,
    "iamt": 14.52,
    "camt": 78.52,
    "samt": 12.9,
    "csamt": 500,
    "val": 1000,
    "custom": {
        "custom_<<attr1_name>>": "",
        "custom_<<attr2_name>>": "",
        "custom_<<attr3_name>>": "",
        "custom_<<attr4_name>>": ""
    }
}]
}
```

Now I want to show for each 'b2b' for each 'ctin' what is total 'txval' and the sum of ('iamt', 'camt', 'samt'). Each itms may have multiple documents in an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks, i was able to do that with unwind but your one is beautiful.

```
db.GSTR2SAVE.aggregate([
                        { $project: { gstin: 1, "b2b.ctin": 1, 
"b2b.itms.itm_det.txval": 1, "b2b.itms.itm_det.iamt": 1, 
"b2b.itms.itm_det.camt": 1, "b2b.itms.itm_det.samt": 1,  
"b2b.itms.itm_det.csamt": 1 } },
                        { $unwind: { path: "$b2b" } },
                        { $unwind: { path: "$b2b.itms" } },
                        { $group: { _id: {ctin: "$b2b.ctin"}, t_txval: 
{$sum: "$b2b.itms.itm_det.txval"}, t_iamt: { $sum: 
"$b2b.itms.itm_det.iamt"}, t_camt: {$sum: "$b2b.itms.itm_det.camt"}, 
t_samt: {$sum: "$b2b.itms.itm_det.samt"}, t_csamt: {$sum: 
"$b2b.itms.itm_det.csamt"}} },
]).pretty()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the result from MongoDB with the aggregation framework using [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) and [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) operators:

```
db.horrible.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "b2b": {
      "$map": {
        "input": "$b2b",
        "as": "b",
        "in": {
          "ctin": "$$b.ctin",
          "txval": { "$sum": "$$b.itms.itm_det.txval" },
          "iamt": { "$sum": "$$b.itms.itm_det.iamt" },
          "camt": { "$sum": "$$b.itms.itm_det.camt" },
          "samt": { "$sum": "$$b.itms.itm_det.samt" }
        }    
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

The [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) operator basically takes an array as input and then processes an expression on each item for the result. In this case we return the `"ctin"` value and the [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) of each of the keys you want totals for from the "inner" `"itms"` array.

I will note however that since you are not really "aggregating" anything we can pretty much simply iterate the cursor and simply apply the same sort of transformation. You save mostly on the data trasferred by simply only returning the keys of the document which you want with a [basic projection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/), in this case just the `"b2b"` array and the default `"_id"`:

This can be done in any language really, but for JavaScript through the MongoDB shell, this basically uses the same [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=example) and [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce?v=example) array methods

```
db.horrible.find({ },{ "b2b": 1 }).map(doc => {
  var obj = { "_id": doc._id };
  obj.b2b = doc.b2b.map(b => {
    var inner = { ctin: b.ctin };
    ["txval", "iamt", "camt", "samt"].forEach( k => 
      inner[k] = b.itms.map( e => e.itm_det[k] ).reduce((a,b) => a + b,0)
    );
    return inner;
  });
  return obj;
})
```

Both approaches produce the same thing:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("594717793468c33cb7523148"),
        "b2b" : [
                {
                        "ctin" : "32DS233TY781233",
                        "txval" : 31000.46,
                        "iamt" : 2600.4,
                        "camt" : 2600.5,
                        "samt" : 100
                },
                {
                        "ctin" : "32DS233TY781234",
                        "txval" : 14000.23,
                        "iamt" : 1200.2,
                        "camt" : 1300.25,
                        "samt" : 0
                },
                {
                        "ctin" : "32DS233TY781235",
                        "txval" : 16000.23,
                        "iamt" : 1300.2,
                        "camt" : 1400.25,
                        "samt" : 0
                }
        ]
}
```

Comment: thanks, i was able to do that with unwind but your one is beautiful.

Comment: thanks, i was able to do that with unwind but your one is beautiful. but unable to print ctin outside the _id {} bracket

Comment: @user2769569 I am somewhat baffled by your response. Your original question title was [How to add single row's similar documents of an array together in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/44618672/1) as you can clearly see in the revision history. I changed the title but not by much, as the same "single row" is stated there. Your own answer here actually can possibly apply to "multiple documents". What I answered is "what your question asked". This is the "single document" summed up. If you would like to see this applied to "multiple documents", then you need but ask.

Comment: @user2769569 As I generally see it though, the question you asked has in fact been answered. If you decide to do something "different" then that is actually outside of the scope of this question. For the sake of future readers, they "should" be pointed at the answer that actually applies to the "question as asked". This is what I believe I have done here.

Comment: understand, thanks for clarifying me. Now for "b2b", i need a sum of all "taxval", sum of all "iamt" .... . No mater what "ctin" value it has.

Comment: @user2769569 If you have a different question then you should [Ask a new Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). If you believe your scope has changed then you should at least indicate that the answer here does indeed answer the question that was asked here. If you understand, then simply accept the answer as you have now been prompted to do several times.